# How to tokenize text by sentences with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, tokenize

I've reached the limit of my knowledge of XSLT with the following problem.

I have an XML file that looks like this, simplified:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<p>
    <w>This</w>
    <w>is</w>
    <w>a</w>
    <w>sentence</w>
    <w>with</w>
    <w>a</w>
    <entity type="name">Name</entity>
    <w>and</w>
    <w>a</w>
    <entity type="place">Place</entity>
    <w>etc</w>. <w>This</w>
    <w>is</w>
    <w>another</w>
    <w>sentence</w>
    <w>with</w>
    <w>an</w>
    <w>abbrev</w>. <w>before</w>
    <w>its</w>
    <w>end</w>. <w>Is</w>
    <w>this</w>
    <w>a</w>
    <w>question</w>? <w>Sure</w>
    <w>it</w>
    <w>is</w>! </p>
</root>
```

The text is already tokenized by word. I need to automatically mark up sentences. To do that, I have a variable that contains possible characters which end a sentence:

```
<xsl:variable name="SEnd">.!?</xsl:variable>
```

So, I need an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet which will:

- loop over each paragraph
- group words (`<w>`) together starting with the first `<w>` in a paragraph and ending with a `<w>` element whose immediate sibling `text()` node starts with one of the members of the variable set "SEnd", but if and only if the `following-sibling::w` starts with a capital letter (this has to be a REGEX `\p{Lu}` and not just `[A-Z]` because I have multiple scripts;
- wrap each of the above-mentioned groups in `<s></s>`.

This way `<w>abbrev</w>.` will not be recognized as the last word of a sentence, because it's followed by a lower-case word.

The result should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<p>
    <s><w>This</w>
        <w>is</w>
        <w>a</w>
        <w>sentence</w>
        <w>with</w>
        <w>a</w>
        <entity type="name">Name</entity>
        <w>and</w>
        <w>a</w>
        <entity type="place">Place</entity>
        <w>etc</w>.</s>
    <s><w>This</w>
        <w>is</w>
        <w>another</w>
        <w>sentence</w>
        <w>with</w>
        <w>an</w>
        <w>abbrev</w>. <w>before</w>
        <w>its</w>
        <w>end</w>.</s>
    <s><w>Is</w>
        <w>this</w>
        <w>a</w>
        <w>question</w>?</s>
    <s><w>Sure</w>,
        <w>it</w>
        <w>is</w>!</s>
</p>
</root>
```

I know that this is not bullet-proof, and that there will be exceptions, but that is not important for this particular task. I understand the problem conceptually, and I think one should use `<xsl:for-each-group>` but I am at a loss how to actually put it all together.

I would very much appreciate your help.

All best,
Tench

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="text()[matches(., $SEnd)][matches(following-sibling::w[1], '^\p{Lu}')]">
            <s>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
            </s>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: yes. yes. yes. thank you so much! now i finally understand what group-ending-with does.